# Google Analytics API returns different data for custom segment

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The revenue for all or our segments is off. In the UI, for January 1st - 31st we see a transactionRevenue of €2663,39 but requesting the revenue for this same segment through the Core Reporting API results in a transactionRevenue of €3316,21. The query used is:
`https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:[profile_id]&metrics=ga:transactionRevenue&start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=2016-01-31&segment=gaid::[segment_id]`

The oddest part is that when recreating the segment (so using the source, medium and campaigns filtered through the segment), we do get the correct amount as seen for the segment in the interface returned. But when we use the segment ID, the data is incorrect...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I also want to add that the request was not sampled. I checked the `containsSampledData` property in the result, and it was `false`.